# Using PHP to cURL This API Authentication Request

Tags: php, api, curl, graphql

I'm encountering a knowledge gap in presenting the following cURL request via PHP to an API built on GraphQL:

```
curl --request POST
     --url https://a.n.domain/graphql 
     --header 'content-type: application/json' 
     --data '{"query":"mutation {\n signIn (apiKey: \"API_KEY\", password: \"ACCOUNT_PASSWORD\")\n {\n token\n }\n}"}'
```

Specifically it's the 'nesting' and the line-breaks within --data that are foxing me.

So far I have:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$auth_data = array(
    "query" => "mutation {\n signIn (apiKey: \"API_KEY\", password: \"ACCOUNT_PASSWORD\")\n {\n token\n }\n}"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $auth_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://a.n.domain/graphql');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```

Obviously, it fails ("Connection Failure"). I'm sure I should break down the query further and lose the '\n's, but how?

Also it happens that the password begins with a $, which confuses PHP. I escape it thus:

`password: \"\$REST_OF_PASSWORD\"`

That should work, right?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing the JSON code by hand, you should use the json_encode function to let PHP generate correctly formatted JSON.